# For a ring $R$, what is $\text{Gr}(R)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm reading Deligne's "The fundamental group of the projective line minus 3 points", specifically the chapter on tangential base points (15.14), where in 15.20, he suddenly uses the notation $Spec\; Gr(R)$, where $R$ is a DVR and $s$ the closed point of Spec $R$. Apparently this is equal to the tangent space of Spec $R$ at $s$.

Any idea what this could mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any local ring $(R, m)$ is naturally a filtered ring, with filtration given by the powers of $m$. $\text{Gr}$ means the [associated graded ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_graded_ring) with respect to the filtration. Its spectrum is the [tangent cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_cone) at $m$.